# How to fix OpenVPN error when using network-manager-openvpn-gnome?

Tags: networking, 18.04, gnome, network-manager, openvpn

I need to connect to some VPN via `OpenVPN`.

I am using `Bionic`.

It works when I run the command as sudo from terminal

```
~$ sudo openvpn --config somevpn.ovpn
...
Sun Jun 10 22:35:31 2018 TUN/TAP device tap0 opened
Sun Jun 10 22:35:31 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sun Jun 10 22:35:31 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tap0 up mtu 1500
Sun Jun 10 22:35:31 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

without sudo it fails

```
~$ openvpn --config somevpn.ovpn
...
Sun Jun 10 22:34:55 2018 ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tap: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Sun Jun 10 22:34:55 2018 Exiting due to fatal error
```

Ok, only sudo can create a TUN/TAP device. I added the user to a vpn group and added that group to sudoer

```
%nm-openvpn ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/openvpn
```

But this only helps on the terminal, that is the user does not need to enter the password when running the command. It does not help when trying to start the VPN connection via `network-manager-openvpn-gnome`.

`network-manager-openvpn-gnome` reports a timeout after a few seconds when that vpn connection is activated.

How can I start that vpn connection successfully through the GUI?

Comment: How are you running network-manager-openvpn-gnome ?

Comment: as part of budgie-desktop, it starts with the user login

Comment: Thanks. I don't know budgie. It works just fine for me through the network manager gui, no sudo required.

Comment: it also works for other vpn connections without sudo  like proton-vpn

Answer (score 0):

Please check your log file for the error message. I had a similar error message when trying to run 'openvpn' from the command line. However when reading the log file the error seemed related to not being able to find the certificates.

In this case I moved my files to the 'Documents' folder, re-imported the file through the Network Manager and then it worked as expected.